# UPDATE query to change just the FIRST duplicate record in Access

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, sql-update

**Example Dataset**

```
TransID   FieldA   FieldB   FieldC   Amount   Status
001       John     Doe      Sr       1.00     Hold
002       John     Doe      Sr       -1.00    Hold
003       John     Doe      Sr       1.00     Hold
```

`Status` is the only field that is not locked in the dataset. It is an enum of three values; "hold" (default), "approved", and "denied".

`TransID` is a unique field.

**My Goal**

I would like to auto-approve any "nullifying" transactions. Thus I'd like to 'auto-approve' transaction 001 and 002 above, but leave 003 in 'hold' status for staff to manually review.

**My Code**

Unfortunately I do not have functioning code to troubleshoot here. Instead looking for some guidance regarding what logic to use.

Part 1: Obviously I'll need an UPDATE query in Access to perform the change of Status. I'm not too worried about that part.

Part 2: How do I identify "nullifying" records?

Part 2a: I could look for duplicate records based on `FieldA`, `FieldB`, `FieldC`.

Part 2b: But then what? What logic should I use to check if `Amount` is = (`Amount` * -1) of another record?

Part 2c: Even if I can identify these records, how would I only approve the "nullifying" records? i.e., Trans 001 and 003 would both fall into the criteria for part 2b, so how would I only approve one of them (use `SELECT TOP 1` maybe?) But then what if there are multiple "nullifying" records? i.e., `Trans` 004 and 005 are exactly the same as 002 and 003?

I'm a bit stumped on this one. Any help with the logic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is mostly impossible to achieve in MS access SQL. You have to write a VBA procedure

Comment: @ThomasG: Yes. Open the table/query as a DAO recordset. Then loop this once or multiple times where you read and sum the values, and update as needed. Far easier to test and maintain than running a series of convoluted queries.

Comment: @Gustav and ThomasG - Thanks for the help! I'm fine with jumping into VBA, but wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking an SQL option. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this is impossible to solve through SQL.

Trans 1 and 2 can be updated to "Approved" if a few assumptions can be made.

1. If the TransIDs of transactions that net out and should be approved have a lower TransID than the ones that should not.
2. Either multiple pairs of "netting" transactions wont occur for the same person, or it's a reasonable solution to repeatedly run an update query until it no longer updates records.

The following is a query that will update pairs of Transactions with the minimum TransID where the names match and the the amount sum is zero.

```
UPDATE [Table1] 
SET [Status] = "Approved"
WHERE [TransID] = (
    SELECT a.minTransID
    FROM (Select Min(TransID) as minTransID, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, Amount
        FROM Table1
        Where Amount > 0
        Group By FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, Amount
        ) a
    INNER JOIN (
        Select Min(TransID) as minTransID, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, Amount
        FROM Table1
        Where Amount < 0 and Status = "Hold"
        Group By FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, Amount
        ) b on a.FieldA = b.FieldA and a.FieldB = b.FieldB and a.FieldC = b.FieldC
    )
OR [TransID] =(
    SELECT B.minTransID
    FROM (Select Min(TransID) as minTransID, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, Amount
        FROM Table1
        Where Amount > 0
        Group By FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, Amount
        ) a
    INNER JOIN (
        Select Min(TransID) as minTransID, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, Amount
        FROM Table1
        Where Amount < 0 and Status = "Hold"
        Group By FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, Amount
        ) b on a.FieldA = b.FieldA and a.FieldB = b.FieldB and a.FieldC = b.FieldC
)
```